# C# legacy project to be refactored, but stuck at a basic if stacking

Tags: c#

So I got a project to refactor and I can't figure out what the best solution for this specific problem would be. I'm trying to reach some kind of elegant few-line-solution, but every idea I have seems to be a dead end. My brain does not work anymore... The original state:

```
public SearchParameterSet(ProviderRequestParameters requestParameters)
    {
        ProviderParameters = requestParameters;

        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByPatient]))
        {
            string patient = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirResourceNames.FhirResourcePatient];
            string[] ids = patient.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var id in ids)
                PatientIds.Add(id);
        }

        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByCase]))
        {
            string patient = requestParameters.RequestParameters[Constants.QueryParamCaseId];
            string[] ids = patient.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var id in ids)
                CaseIds.Add(id);
        }

        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByDateFrom]))
        {
            string value = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByDateFrom]];
            DateTime df = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out df))
                DateFrom = df;
        }
        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByDateTo]))
        {
            string value = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByDateTo]];
            DateTime df = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out df))
                DateTo = df;
        }
        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.Profile]))
        {
            string value = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.Profile]];
            Profile = value;
        }
        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.Format]))
        {
            string value = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.Format]];
            Format = value;
        }

        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ResourceType]))
        {
            string value = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ResourceType]];
            ResourceType = value;
        }

        if (requestParameters.RequestParameters.ContainsKey(FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByUser]))
        {
            string value = requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByUser]];
            User = value;
        }
    }
```

Currently I am iterating through requestParameters and call the appropriate function depending on the Parameter itself. Also wrote an extension method to be able to get the name of the parameter more nicely. But there has to be a more elegant and complex solution.

```
private List<String> ExtractParametersAsListOfString(string input)
{
    var ret = new List<string>();

    string[] ids = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var id in ids)
        ret.Add(id);

   return ret;
}

private DateTime ExtractParametersAsDateTime(string input)
{
    DateTime df = DateTime.MinValue;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out df))
        DateFrom = df;

    return df;
}

public SearchParameterSet(ProviderRequestParameters requestParameters)
{
    ProviderParameters = requestParameters;

    foreach (var parameter in requestParameters.RequestParameters)
    {
        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.ByPatient.GetName())
            PatientIds = ExtractParametersAsListOfString(parameter.Value);

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.ByCase.GetName())
            CaseIds = ExtractParametersAsListOfString(parameter.Value);

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.ByDateFrom.GetName())
            DateFrom = ExtractParametersAsDateTime(parameter.Value);

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.ByDateTo.GetName())
            DateTo = ExtractParametersAsDateTime(parameter.Value);

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.Profile.GetName())
            Profile = parameter.Value;

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.Format.GetName())
            Format = parameter.Value;

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.ResourceType.GetName())
            ResourceType = parameter.Value;

        if (parameter.Key == FhirRequestParameters.ByUser.GetName())
            User = parameter.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirResourceNames.FhirResourcePatient];` a typo (same for ByCase) as everywhere else you've used the format `requestParameters.RequestParameters[FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[FhirRequestParameters.ByPatient]]`?  Also otherwise your ContainsKey code doesn't check the same key that your later fetch uses.

Comment: Yes, good find, that was a bug that was actually corrected.

Comment: Also, can you share the data types?  I'm guessing `requestParameters.RequestParameters` is `IDictionary<string,string>` and those properties using `Add` (e.g. `PatientIds`) are `IList<string>`s?

Comment: This question is so bad an uclear that I don't get it how it got so many upvotes already... could you tell us please what is the purpose of it and what you are exacly doing here?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Runnable Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qPCoKu

Update: 2018-10-26 Tweaked code slightly so the CSV piece returns an array then uses `AddRange` to add values to the lists, instead of having to pass a reference to the lists themselves (i.e. allows more consistent behavior, and gives more re-usable code).  Also includes an extension method to provide `AddRange` on an `IList<T>`.

---

I've made a few assumptions about what your classes look like / outlined those in the code below.

I'm not sure what benefit `FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames` adds, as it seems you've already got your parameter names defined in `FhirRequestParameters`; so you may be duplicating effort there... but without knowing more I can't really comment.

Beyond that, you've correctly identified that there's a lot of repetition in your code which makes for a good refactor candidate.  I've attempted to do this by having one method to fetch back the values from your requestParameters object, and allowing that to take a function which can convert from the string to the required type / returning default values where applicable.

I've put the split to  list piece in a separate function to the passed function, since your code assumes that the list has already been initialised; so I don't want to overwrite the existing value, but rather only add the new items to this existing list.

Hopefully the code speaks for itself.  Apologies for any issues; knocked up in a text editor / untested so far...  Please let me know in the comments if any questions or issues.

```
//assumption: your parameters are in an IDictionary:
//public class ProviderRequestParameters{public IDictionary<string,string> RequestParameters{get;}}
public class SearchParameterSet
{
    //Assumption: based on your code I assume you have properties something like this
    public ProviderRequestParameters ProviderParameters {get;set;}
    private IList<string> patientIds = new List<string>();
    public IList<string> PatientIds {get{return patientIds;} set {patientIds = value;}} 
    private IList<string> caseIds = new List<string>();
    public IList<string> CaseIds {get{return caseIds;} set {caseIds = value;}} 
    public DateTime DateFrom {get;set;} 
    public DateTime DateTo {get;set;} 
    public string Profile {get;set;} 
    public string Format {get;set;} 
    public string ResourceType {get;set;} 
    public string User {get;set;} 

    //actual changes below based on the above assumptions
    public SearchParameterSet(ProviderRequestParameters requestParameters)
    {
        var rParams = requestParameters.RequestParameters;

        ProviderParameters = requestParameters;

        PatientIds.AddRange(RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<IEnumerable<string>>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.ByPatient, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnCsvStrings));
        CaseIds.AddRange(RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<IEnumerable<string>>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.ByCase, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnCsvStrings));
        DateFrom = RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<DateTime>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.ByDateFrom, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnDate);
        DateTo = RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<DateTime>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.ByDateTo, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnDate);
        Profile = RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<string>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.Profile, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnString);
        Format = RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<string>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.Format, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnString);
        ResourceType = RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<string>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.ResourceType, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnString);
        User = RequestParameterHelper.GetValueOrDefault<string>(rParams, FhirRequestParameters.ByUser, RequestParameterHelper.ReturnString);
    }
}

public static class RequestParameterHelper
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(IDictionary<string, string> requestParameters, string key, Func<string, T> parseValue)
    {
        string value = null;
        var parameterName = FhirSearchExtensions.RequestParameterNames[key]; //Ideally we wouldn't need this, but I don't know your code well enough to say if we can remove it
        requestParameters.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value); //or use key if the above line can be removed
        return parseValue(value);   
    }
    public static string ReturnString(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
    public static DateTime ReturnDate(string value)
    {
        return DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime result) ? result : DateTime.MinValue;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReturnCsvStrings(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        return value.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}



public static class IListExtension //thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104162/361842
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

        if (list is List<T>)
        {
            ((List<T>)list).AddRange(items);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```